# Why can't I switch UIGestureRecognizer's properties in the action function

Tags: swift, uigesturerecognizer

I have two `UITapGestureRecognizer` to handle both a single tap and a double tap. My code is like this:

```
let doubleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(
    target: self, action: #selector(viewController.handleDouble)
)
doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
myview.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTap)

let singleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(
    target: self, action: #selector(viewController.handleSingle)
)
singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
singleTap.require(toFail: doubleTap)
myview.addGestureRecognizer(singleTap)
```

And `handelDouble` and `handleSingle` are the functions handle double and single taps. This works perfectly well.

Now I would like to just create one `UITapGestureRecognizer` to handle both case, something like:

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(
    target: self, action: #selector(viewController.handleTap(recognizer:))
)
myview.addGestureRecognizer(Tap)
```

And in the `handelTap` function I wrote like this:

```
func handleTap(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    switch recognizer.state {
    case .ended:
        if (recognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2) {
             // to do something with double tapping
        } else {
             // to do something with single tapping
        }
    default: break
    }
}
```

However, this does not work. More weird is that when double tapping, things for single tapping happens.

This also happens to `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` as I cannot using one function to select which direction it is.

So is it that we can only create multiple `UIGestureRecognizer` instances for such work?

Answer (score 0):

In your code you `numberOfTapsRequired` for `singleTap` is equal `2`. I think correct value would be `1`

```
let singleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(
    target: self, action: #selector(viewController.handleSingle)
)
singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
singleTap.require(toFail: doubleTap)
myview.addGestureRecognizer(singleTap)
```

Comment: Edited, but question still remain